What is the proper way to deal with questions that are off-topic?
Sometimes questions get posted to the site which are off-topic or outside the scope of this site. What is the best way to deal with such questions?

If you encounter a question which you feel is off topic, you can vote to close the question if you have enough reputation. The amount of reputation varies based on what stage of the beta we are in; the amount needed is listed on the privileges page. During the private beta, everyone can vote to close. To vote to close a question, click the "close" link underneath the question:

If you do not have enough reputation to cast a close vote, or if you feel the question is on-topic somewhere else, you can flag the topic for moderator attention. Underneath each question is a "flag" link which you can click to inform the moderators that the question needs attention:

You can then use the flag dialog to inform the moderators where you do feel the question belongs:

As our site grows and more questions are closed the top 5 migration paths will become available to users with close votes. Until that time, only moderators can migrate questions because the only site we are able to migrate questions to ourselves is https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/. So during the early beta, if a question belongs on another site, flag it.
If someone tells you that your question is off-topic and belongs on another site, do not re-post the question there. Flag your own question and ask a moderator to move it. Cross posting is not permitted on Stack Exchange.
